# How to create virtual host xampp windows 7

Tags: php, windows, xampp, localhost, host

Here I create virtual host in xampp windows 7 but it did not work, when I open it shows **Bad Request**

> Error: Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

**httpd-vhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_login"
ServerName www.ci_login.local
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
```

**Hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1       www.ciadmin.local
127.0.0.1       www.ci_login.local
```

Comment: Restarted your server after adding the vhost?

Comment: yes already restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. See error and/or access log in directories below for errors.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_login"
    ServerName www.ci_login.local
    ServerAlias ci_login.local
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_login/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_login/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```